# HOWTO tf.estimator with continuous and categorical columns

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tf.estimator which works for continuous variables and I want to expand it to use categorical variables.

Consider a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
label           |  con_col          |  cat_col
(float 0 or 1)  |  (float -1 to 1)  |  (int 0-3)
----------------+-------------------+---------------
0               |   0.123           |  2
0               |   0.456           |  1
1               |  -0.123           |  3
1               |  -0.123           |  3
0               |   0.123           |  2
```

To build the estimator for just the label and the continuous variable column (con_col) I build the following feature_column variable.

```
feature_cols = [
                   tf.feature_column.numeric_column('con_col')
               ]
```

Then I pass it to the DNNClassifer like so.

```
tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_cols ...)
```

Later I build a serving_input_fn().  In this function I also specify the columns. This routine is quite small and looks like this:

```
def serving_input_fn(): 
    feat_placeholders['con_col'] = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None])

    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(feat_placeholders.copy(), feat_placeholders)
```

This works.  However, when I try to use the categorical column I have a problem.

So using the categorical column, this part seems to work.

```
feature_cols = [
    tf.feature_column.sequence_categorical_column_with_identity('cat_col', num_buckets=4))
               ]
tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_cols ...)
```

For the serving_input_fn() I get suggestions from the stack trace but both suggestions fail.:

```
def serving_input_fn(): 
    # try #2
    # this fails
    feat_placeholders['cat_col'] = tf.SequenceCategoricalColumn(categorical_column=tf.IdentityCategoricalColumn(key='cat_col', number_buckets=4,default_value=None))

    # try #1
    # this also fails
    # feat_placeholders['cat_col'] = tf.feature_column.indicator_column(tf.feature_column.sequence_categorical_column_with_identity(column, num_buckets=4))

    # try #0
    # this fails. Its using the same form for the con_col
    # the resulting error gave hints for the above code.
    # Note, i'm using this url as a guide.  My cat_col is
    # is similar to that code samples 'dayofweek' except it
    # is not a string.
    # https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/master/courses/machine_learning/feateng/taxifare_tft/trainer/model.py
    #feat_placeholders['cat_col'] = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None])


    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(feat_placeholders.copy(), feat_placeholders)
```

This is the error message if try #0 is used.

```
ValueError: Items of feature_columns must be a <class 'tensorflow.python.feature_column.feature_column_v2.DenseColumn'>. You can wrap a categorical column with an embedding_column or indicator_column. Given: SequenceCategoricalColumn(categorical_column=IdentityCategoricalColumn(key='cat_col', number_buckets=4, default_value=None))
```

**Lak's answer implementation**

Using Lak's answer as a guide, this works for both both feature columns.

```
# This is the list of features we pass as an argument to DNNClassifier
feature_cols = []

# Add the continuous column first
feature_cols.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column('con_col'))                  

# Add the categorical column which is wrapped?
# This creates new columns from a single column?
category_feature_cols = [tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_identity('cat_col', num_buckets=4)]
for c in category_feature_cols:
    feat_cols.append(tf.feature_column.indicator_column(c))

# now pass this list to the DNN
tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_cols ...)


def serving_input_fn(): 
    feat_placeholders['con_col'] = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None])
    feat_placeholders['cat_col'] = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap categorical columns before sending to DNN:

```
cat_feature_cols = [ tf.feature_column.sequence_categorical_column_with_identity('cat_col', num_buckets=4)) ]
feature_cols = [tf.feature_column.indicator_column(c) for c in cat_feature_cols]
```

Use indicator column to one-hot encode, or embedded column to embed.

Comment: Thanks Lak I’ll try this today

Comment: Hmm. I am having troubles with this.  If I understand correctly, I need to do the wrapping of feature_cols before I pass to `tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_cols ...)`.  As far as the `serving_input_fn()` body, it simply specifies all features as tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None])`